# XGBOOST Model predicting, with nan Input values

Tags: python, classification, xgboost

I am facing a weird behavior in the xgboost classifier. Reproducing the code from a response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082381/xgboost-produce-prediction-result-and-probability) post

```
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

xgb_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
xgb_clf = xgb_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(xgb_clf.predict(X_test))
print(xgb_clf.predict_proba(X_test))

>>[0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]
[[0.97378635 0.02621362]
 [0.97106457 0.0289354 ]
 [0.45146966 0.54853034]
 [0.9181994  0.08180059]
 [0.97378635 0.02621362]
 [0.4264453  0.5735547 ]
 [0.6279408  0.37205923]
 [0.991474   0.00852604]
 [0.06204838 0.9379516 ]
 [0.08833408 0.9116659 ]]
```

So far so good. However , when the input contains all nan values, even then the model makes a prediction.

```
b = np.empty([3,2])
b[:] = np.nan
xgb_clf.predict_proba(b)

>>array([[0.8939177 , 0.10608231],
   [0.8939177 , 0.10608231],
   [0.8939177 , 0.10608231]], dtype=float32)
```

This caught me completely off-guard. Am I missing some parameter , that can make the classifier prediction output also nan

Comment: np.nan is a floating point number, it has defined behavior when used in arithmetics and comparisons. Thus you can run the model on np.nan, but don't expect meaninfullness, because it's "out of range" for what the model was trained for

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov xgboost treats np.nan specially as "missing" values. When the training set has missings, it will try to learn useful information from the missingness itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official docs says:

> XGBoost supports missing values by default. In tree algorithms, branch directions for missing values are learned during training. Note that the gblinear booster treats missing values as zeros.

> When the missing parameter is specifed, values in the input predictor that is equal to missing will be treated as missing and removed. By default it’s set to NaN.

So this is the expected behavior! And there is a "missing" parameter in the API that you can set to change (sort of) this behavior.

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. If you want to override the model's predictions, you'll have to do that manually.